# Get-PnPListItem -FolderServerRelativeUrl not finding folder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Cannot for the life of me get the Get-PnPListItem working. it works in a different domain but not under the current working one

To confirm that the folder im looking for exists. running Get-PnPFolder spits out the following

```
Get-PnPFolder -Url "/sites/MIPS/Shared Documents/General/Information/Public Documents"

Name             Type   Items/Size Last Modified        
----             ----   ---------- -------------        
Public Documents Folder         43 19/04/2020 2:58:10 AM
```

So in theory. running the following command should give me a list of documents

```
Get-PnPListItem -List "Public Documents" -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/MIPS/Shared Documents/General/Information/"
Get-PnPListItem : No list found with id, title or url 'Public Documents'
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPListItem -List "Public Documents" -FolderServerRelativeUrl "si ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPListItem], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetListItem
```

I have tried all forms of different versions of syntax for the paths etc but none seem to work..

halp

Comment: Can you perhaps pipe the returned object from the first cmdlet to the second: `Get-PnPFolder -Url "/sites/MIPS/Shared Documents/General/Information/Public Documents" | Get-PnPListItem`?

Comment: "Public Documents" is a folder, not a list. Use "Shared Document" for the -List parameter and include "Public Documents" in the -FolderServerRelativeUrl, as you did for -Url in the first sample.